# Ellipse Tool in Python part 2

Tags: python, pygame, paint, draw, ellipse

I am currently making changes to the way my ellipse tool works as it was not working the correct way previously. I am creating it for my paint program using python 2.7.5 and pygame.  I have recently encountered this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Wisdom1\Desktop\Comp Science Files\Canvas.py", line 164, in <module>
draw.ellipse(screen,(c),(x,y,radx,rady),sz2)
ValueError: width greater than ellipse radius
```

This occurs when I try to create an ellipse going in every direction except downward to the right from a point.  I understand the error I just do not know how to fix it.  Here is my ellipse tool:

```
if mb[0] == 1 and canvas.collidepoint(mx,my):
        screen.set_clip(canvas)
        if tool == "ellipse":
            screen.blit(copy,(0,0))
            radx = max(mx-x,1)
            rady = max(my-y,1)
            draw.ellipse(screen,(c),(x,y,radx,rady),sz2)
        screen.set_clip(None)
```

Sz2 is a size variable that begins at 10 and decreases or increases by 3 each time the mouse wheel is moved down or up.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a ternary statement in the form of:

```
draw.ellipse(screen,(c),(x,y,radx,rady), sz2 if sz2 < max(radx, raxy) else 0)
```

Sincerely,

Another Massey student working on a Sunday night ;)

Answer (score 0):

If `sz2`, the thickness of the curve, is greater than the minor radius of the ellipse, pygame raises a `ValueError`.  So you could protect against this by using an `if-statement`:

```
if sz2 < min(radx, rady)//2:
    pygame.draw.ellipse(self.screen, green, box, sz2)
else:
    # sz2=0 fills the ellipse
    pygame.draw.ellipse(self.screen, green, box, 0)
```

`radx`, `rady` is the width and height of the `Rect` bounding the ellipse. So the minor radius is half the smaller of `radx` and `rady`.

---

Here is some runnable code showing that the `if-statement` works:

```
"""Based on http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/intro/intro.html"""
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()
size = (width, height) = (320, 240)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
black = (0,0,0)
green = [0, 255, 0]
radx, rady = 50, 70
box = [160-radx//2, 120-rady//2, radx, rady]
width = 1
delta = 2
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ((event.type == pygame.QUIT) or 
            (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and 
             event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE)): 
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill(black)
    if 0 < width < min(radx, rady)//2:
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, green, box, width)
    else:
        if width > 0:
            pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, green, box, 0)
        delta *= -1
    width += delta
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(100)
```